# Retrieving contents from a branch using octokit

Tags: c#, octokit.net

I have recently started to use the octokit library to retrieve data from a github repository.

I can form a search request like

```
   var request = new SearchCodeRequest("ValueSets", "xyzconnect", "projectA")
        {
            // we can restrict search to the file, path or search both
            In = new[] {  CodeInQualifier.Path },
        };

   var result = await client.Search.SearchCode(request);
```

or retrieve directly using

```
   var xsx1 = await client.Repository.Content.GetAllContents(repository.Id, "ValueSets");
```

This works fine when I am using the default branch (usually master) but how do I perform the same functions against other branches?

**EDIT**

So to get content from branches you use the API as such

```
   var xsx2 = await client.Repository.Content.GetAllContentsByRef(repository.Id, "ValueSets","develop");
```

Comment: So I've found the answer to half of the question - it's just the search component that I'm still stuck on.